# Is there any closed curve whose area is proportional to its perimeter?

Tags: geometry, curves

The question is in the title: **Is there any closed curve whose area is proportional to its perimeter?**

If not, why is it so? Can it be proved?

I tried all the simple shapes I know, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Are you looking for a family of shapes, or a single shape? When area = perimeter for a given shape, it is known as "Equable"; [See the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equable_shape#:~:text=A%20two%2Ddimensional%20equable%20shape,unitless%20numerical%20value%20of%2030.). I presume you mean a family of shapes, otherwise a $4 \times 4$ square is a trivial example. If this is the case though, you have to better define what such a family should look like to satisfy your question

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that as you scale a shape (i.e. taking shapes with larger area that are similar) the perimeter changes linearly while the area changes quadratically, so you can't have a family of similar shapes with your desired property.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I meant a family of shapes

Comment: You should specify what you desire of such a family then, since your family cannot be similar (I feel this means the answer to your question is thus "no, this is impossible", though it depends on what sort of family you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get more proportional than equality. There is a family of rectangles whose perimeters are equal to their areas:

- They have sides for the form $x + \sqrt{x^2-4x}$ and $x - \sqrt{x^2-4x}$ with $x \ge 4$
- and so perimeters and areas each equal to $4x$.

Nice examples from this family are

- $x = 4$ gives $4\times4 = 16$
- $x = 4.5$ gives $6\times3 = 18$
- $x = 6.25$ gives $10\times2.5 = 25$